# Why swagger dont display controller endpoints?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core project with Swagger for API documentation. However, I've encountered an issue where Swagger UI is not displaying my controllers as expected it displays only minimal API. Here's an outline of my project setup and the problem I'm facing
[image]

It's supposed to display the controller endpoint but it doesn't it only displays minimal API why?
[image]

and here is the controller endpoint
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

this is the controller code

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MyBGList.DTO;

namespace MyBGList.Controllers
{

    [EnableCors("AnyOrigin")]
    public class BoardGamesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<BoardGamesController> _logger;
        public BoardGamesController(ILogger<BoardGamesController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        [HttpGet(Name = "GetBoardGames")]
        [ResponseCache(Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Any, Duration = 60)]
        public RestDTO<List<BoardGame>> Get()
        {
            var restDTO = new RestDTO<List<BoardGame>>();
            restDTO.Data = new List<BoardGame>
            {
                new BoardGame()
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Name = "Axis & Allies",
                    Year = 1981
                },
                new BoardGame()
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    Name = "Citadels",
                    Year = 2000
                },
                new BoardGame()
                {
                    Id = 3,
                    Name = "Terraforming Mars",
                    Year = 2016
                }
            };
            restDTO.Links = new List<LinkDTO>
            {
                new LinkDTO(Url.Action(null, "BoardGames", null, Request.Scheme), "self", "GET")
            };
            return restDTO;
        }
    }
}
```

program.cs code

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at 
https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddCors(config =>
{
    config.AddDefaultPolicy(options =>
    {

        options.WithOrigins(builder.Configuration["AllowedOrigins"]);
        options.AllowAnyHeader();
        options.AllowAnyMethod();
    });
    config.AddPolicy(name: "AnyOrigin", options =>
    {
        options.AllowAnyOrigin();
        options.AllowAnyHeader();
        options.AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
if (app.Configuration.GetValue<bool>
("UseDeveloperExceptionPage"))
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapGet("/error", () => Results.Problem());
app.MapGet("/error/test", () =>
{
    throw new
 InvalidDataException();
});
app.MapGet("/cod/test", [EnableCors("AnyOrigin")]
[ResponseCache(NoStore = true)] () =>

    Results.Text($@"
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>JavaScript Test</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <script>
                            window.alert(`this is`)
                      </script>
                    <noscript>Your client does not support 
      JavaScript</noscript>
                </body>
            </html>",
        "text/html")

);
app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: please share/copy your code and not a snapshot.

Comment: @MaythamFahmi i edited the question and added the code of the project

Comment: I answered and you are welcome to give some feedback or accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you mistakenly forgot to define the controller and routing by adding the attribute of ApiController and the route attribute.

If you add the following missings, in your controller class it will work:

```
[ApiController]         <-- is missing in your code
[Route("[controller]")] <-- is missing in your code
[EnableCors("AnyOrigin")]
public class BoardGamesController : ControllerBase
etc...
```